# Is neo4j good for storing general nosql data?

Tags: neo4j, graphdb, nosql

I am working on a project which has a complex user management layer with multiple user group levels, team and user heirarchies. So I was thinking about using neo4j. But there is other kind of data also which need to be stored. I'm skeptical about using two separate databases for user management and nonuser data storage.. Is it a good idea to use neo4j itself for both ? The non user data I'm going to store is nosql type data ( json data mostly)

Comment: Are you ever going to be querying into the JSON data itself, or is this only for storage and retrieval as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "general NoSQL data" is essentially meaningless, since there are so [many different types of non-relational DBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Types_and_examples_of_NoSQL_databases) -- each with its own strengths and weaknesses.

You need to look at the characteristics of *your* data and *your* use cases to see whether any particular DB technology is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything you like in neo4j... depends on the size of your data, for smaller datasets you can store everything in neo4j, for bigger one the trend right now ( I think) is to store meta-data in neo4j and jsons(raw data) in mongoDB